# Nginx doesn't show the react page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm creating a microservices system that will be deployed on EC2 via docker, at the moment I have two microservices: nginx and serverUI, nginx contains nginx.conf and a folder with SSL certificates and a Dockerfile that creates the image for me

nginx.conf file:

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://client;
   }  
}
```

nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

then I have a ServerUI microservice which contains a webservice formed by React (client folder) and express (server folder). In the client folder I have a Dockerfile which creates the react image for me

Client Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /client
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm i
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

in the main root I have a docker-compose file which starts all microservices for me
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - client
    restart: always
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs

  client:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./serverUI/client
    volumes:
      - /client/node_modules
      - ./serverUI/client:/client
```

I'm currently trying to launch it locally and for now I'd like to run react without building the application. When I run docker composed both nginx and react, but if I go to the browser at "localhost" I see the default nginx page, how can I fix it?

[image: Root folder]

[image: output of "docker-compose up --build" command]

Answer (score 0):

Provably your nginx.conf file dose not worked by `default.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` directive. So your nginx.conf would have loaded with no problem. But, In `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` server directive, you can see `listen 80;` and it has priority for localhost by `server_name localhost;` directive.

So, you need disable `default.conf` for applying your `nginx.conf`.
If you want to use config in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as it is, remove default.conf. if not, just replace `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with your nginx.conf by changing Dockerfile COPY statement.